# What does the skull and crossbones on the Nazi uniform represent?

Tags: nazi-germany, uniform

I was watching *[The Boy in Striped Pyjamas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_in_the_Striped_Pyjamas_%28film%29)*, and I saw this skull and crossbones on this Nazi's cap.

[image: Resized Image of skull and crossbones.]

Why is it there? (That is, what does this represent?)

Comment: This video does a fine job of exploring the question of the meaning and purpose of the insignia. Well worth watching if you have this question in mind. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToKcmnrE5oY

Comment: Note that it was generally the SS that had the particular insignia, as well as panzer (armored) forces

Comment: My Professional Historian girlfriend just did an image search for totenkopf on google; it is clearly a symbol with an extensive, diverse history.  She points out that the Hussars had it long before Hugo Boss.   The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totenkopf) page provides an adequate answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The skull and crossbones or "death's head" is not a purely German - still less a specifically Nazi - symbol, but has been, and still is,  used by many military units, including the British,  Australian and Swedish armies and the US Marine Corps. The British Queen's Royal Lancers use the skull and crossbones with the caption beneath "Or Glory" - the "Death or Glory boys",  and 100 Squadron RAF fly it on their flag. It would appear to be a sign of commitment to die fighting, rather than mere "baddassery".

See:  [Totenkopf (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totenkopf).

Comment: It was also used by some Polish units during 1919-1920 war against Soviet Russia.

Comment: As well as the US Navy,  I've seen it on several of it's [planes](https://www.deviantart.com/comradeloganov/art/Vought-V-507-F-14A-Vagabond-VF-84-Jolly-Rogers-399760503).

Answer (score 26):

The deaths head (Totenkopf) is a symbol that had been in use by many German and Prussian military units in history, going back hundreds of years. It was mainly to signify their high levels of badassery.  The SS picked up on this and used it themselves to co-opt that history to mold themselves as an elite force.

> Use of the symbol as a military insignia began with the cavalry of the Prussian army under Frederick the Great. Frederick formed Husaren-Regiment Nr. 5 (von Ruesch), a Hussar regiment commanded by Colonel von Ruesch. These Hussars adopted a black uniform with a Totenkopf emblazoned on the front of their mirlitons and wore it on the field in the War of Austrian Succession and in the Seven Years' War.
>
> In 1808, when the regiment was reformed into Leib-Husaren Regiments Nr.1 and Nr.2, the Totenkopf remained a part of the uniform. During the Napoleonic Wars, when Frederick William, Duke of Brunswick-Wolfenbüttel, was killed in battle, his troops changed the colour of their uniforms to black or apple green, with a Totenkopf on their shakos in mourning their dead leader. Other sources claim that the "Black Brunswickers" were so equipped while Friedrich Wilhelm of Brunswick lived, as a sign of revenge on the French.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totenkopf)
>
> The skull continued to be used throughout the Prussian and Brunswick Armed forces until 1918, and some of the stormtroopers that led the last German offensives on the Western Front in 1918 used skull badges.[2]

from [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totenkopf)

Comment: _"his troops changed the colour of their uniforms to black or apple green"_ would that be _from_ black _to_ apple green? It previously mentions it is already black, so I'm getting confused.

Comment: Brunswick led a number of units. I read this that some units changed uniforms or adopted new ones and added the deaths head to match those Hussars. Again, the key seems to be a tradition to adopt a death's head and black uniforms when wanting to show determination or elite skill.

Comment: They even had a SS division named Totenkopf. SS (or nazi in general) symbols are all about co-opting older symbols for the nazis' own purposes - all part of propaganda. The swastika was a luck/eastern/esoteric symbol; the runes were the old nordic 'master race' alphabet; the eagles (see Aquila on wiki) and fasces were imperial symbols;   Besides that, asking when skull+bones become a symbol of death or badassery, is like asking when an arrow become a symbol of direction. Or semiotically speaking, it is not a symbol, its an icon/index which even a caveman understand.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said the symbol is very, very old. The meaning is both "loyalty unto death" and about remembering your own mortality, not "badassery" or anything else.
An excellent reference on the subject is "Death's Head" by Joost Holscher.

As a symbol for soldiers it pre-dates even that by pirates actually. As others have stated it was used by almost all European armed forces.
The history of its use for the Germans begins with the Purussian hussars in the 18th Century and the Brunswick forces who went to fight for the British in the Napoleonic wars.
It stayed as a famous and respected symbol for the Prussian Lieb hussars into the early 20th century and then was absorbed into the German army. 
The Nazis tried to co-opt it in the 1930s in order to cash in on its extensive history with the German army. The army protested this however so the Nazi version had to be altered with the addition of a rather goofy oversized jaw to placate them. 
The totenkopf used by the SS is different from that used by the German army in WW2.

It's also largely an exaggeration (approaching a myth) that Hugo Boss had much of an influence on the look of Nazi uniforms: those uniforms were based on a universal style used by almost all armies since before WW 1, from Australia to the USA, to Japan etc. The style originated in Britain in the late 19th century. Actually it was already present in Prussia at the time of Frederic the Great, whose inspiration for this emblem might have come from some Pandurs units. Two Prussian hussars regiments used this symbol at this time :the 5th and 8th, the later even shown a complete skeleton on its shako. And a "Death hussars" unit also existed during the french revolution, between September 1792 and April 1793.They were dressed in black with the skull and crossbones on the top of their jacket sleeves and on the sabretache.

Comment: Can you please expand on the last paragraph? +1 anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think SS uniform skull is in any way related to similar insignia in other nations, as suggested by @TheHonRose. I believe it was introduced by Hugo Boss circa 1933 when he designed Nazi uniforms, and the meaning of it was something like "Loyal until death". I don't recall the reference though; you may want to look into early history of Hugo Boss fashion house.

Now, as to where Hugo Boss got the idea of putting a skull on SS uniforms - that I don't know; Oldcat's conjecture about Totenkopf sounds very plausible.

Comment: "I don't think.... as suggested by @TheHonRose."  - we're left with two conflicting opinions.  Can you provide evidence to help us resolve the conflict?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, I don't have evidence apart from a web search long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Seven answers and nobody has gone back further than the 18th century?

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skull_and_crossbones_(symbol)):

> From at least the 12th century, it has been used for military flags or
>   insignia and as a warning of the ferocity of the unit displaying it.
>   It became associated with piracy from the 14th century onwards,
>   possibly even earlier. By the 15th century, the symbol had developed
>   into its familiar form.
>
> The Knights Templar organisation, active from the 12th until their
>   demise in 1307, adopted a skull-and-crossbones flag to identify ships
>   belonging to their vast fleet. The later Knights of Malta, made up
>   of many former Templars and using the same flag, became known for
>   piracy. The skull and crossbones as a pirate's flag could well predate
>   the Knights Templar

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of the death's head is to function as a [memento mori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori) ("remember, you will die").

If a soldier always keeps in front of him the reminder of the inevitability of death, he will fight bravely in battle, because it is better to die in battle, than in bed as a decrepit old man.

**UPDATE**

It is quite well documented what I wrote above. There have been death's head units in Germany going back to the time of Frederick the Great. Two of the well-known units were the Black Hussars and the Brunswickers. The Brunswickers at one time actually had the words "Momento Mori" written on the badge itself. In other words, the skull and bones had the words "Momento Mori written right under it on their uniform. Here is a 19th-century comment on the badge from a Scottish magazine:

[image]

Comment: **“Moment mori”**? More like a symbol designed to strike fear into enemies. Unless you can provide some historical evidence of skull and bones being used explicitly as a memento mori.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: Correct answer: downvote it. Wrong answer with random anecdotes and irrelevant quotes that kind of sound right: upvote it.

Comment: This is a relevant answer. I wonder why they downvote it.

Comment: @Rohit People don't like answers that controvert their own ignorance and preconceptions. What they like is bland answers that fit with their own notions and list random, irrelevant pseudo "authorities" like the Wikipedia and books from second-rate journalists. Most people vote on factors having nothing to do with whether an answer is a legitimate answer or not or whether it is correct. Multiple people have said specifically they downvote my answers because they "don't like my attitude".

Comment: Yeah right. Unscholarly and unobjective. Alternate views, most often , add to the discussion, unless there are people, eager to be rid of the uncertainty of open endedness, and eager to conclude with secure , comfortable answers. And i like your attitude, that cynical humour..... :)

Comment: @TylerDurden  An answer may be wrong or right, we disagree, That is our right, But we can surely keep it polite? Your "attitude" I may condemn, But never stoop to "ad hominem".

Comment: bones and skulls were also used in cemeteries, crypts, including bone-made chapels. Also in books with the sense of 'memento mori'. It is such as obvious sign of death that it may mean both senses, 'memento mori', and 'we are badass and we will kill you', as the context requires and the interpreter wishes. Just enter 'memento mori medieval' on google images and you will get plenty, including danse macabre. There is even 'memento mori' at wiki with a bones+skull right in the beggining. A country might very well want that the soldiers understand both senses. Be prepared kill but also to die.

Answer (score -2):

The Skull and Cross bones Has been used for hundreds of years by many 
country's army's, it symbolises Honor unto death in the protection of the homeland it is not about race The USA & Russia Britain Still use the Skull and Cross bones Today in many of their units

Comment: Sounds plausible, However, it would be helpful if you could source some of the statements made in this answer.

Answer (score -3):

The Skull and Cross bones represents a member of the SS. The Da in the movie was a concentration camp Kommandant, he commanded the camp which would more than likely make him a member of the SS.

Comment: What is a "Da"?

Comment: The skull and crossbones long predates the establishment of the SS in the 1930's, going back more than a 150 years before that.